# Multiple implementation of same bean

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am implementing same interface in two classes, and using @Resource annotation to make the difference but I am unable to under the concept here, just mentioning an name in the resource annotation . How spring going for right implementation?

Implementation classes are HomeBankingDaoImpl and HomeBankingDaoImplTwo.

```
@Autowired  
@Resource(name="homeBankingDaoImpl")
HomeBankingDao homeBankingDao;
@RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(ModelMap model){
    System.out.println("###########################");
    model.addAttribute("signup",new Signup());
    return "login";
}
```

Comment: Your two implementing classes are Spring Bean objects, and Spring Beans have names. If you don't explicitly name a Spring Bean, Spring will name it after the unqualified class name, e.g. class `HomeBankingDaoImpl` becomes bean name `homeBankingDaoImpl`, and the `name` attribute of the `@Resource` names the bean to use.

Comment: Why are you using `@Resource` & `@Autowired` both?

Comment: yeah i need to remove autowired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `@Resource` with `@Qualifier`

```
@Autowired  
@Qualifier(name="homeBankingDaoImpl")
HomeBankingDao homeBankingDao;
@RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(ModelMap model){
    System.out.println("###########################");
    model.addAttribute("signup",new Signup());
    return "login";
}
```

There are many sources available on internet to understand `@Qualifier`. 
Here is one simple tutorial for your understanding: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_qualifier_annotation.htm